# CSS `transform` is affecting `background-attachment`

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, css-transforms

Using CSS `transform` on a parent element affects all other children and their `background-attachment` properties.

In the example I'm providing, I am faking the acrylic blur effect inside the children elements.

The issue occurs when I'm trying to imitate the animation of a window spawning, where the window opacity is set to 0, and the animation kicks in that scales that window from `scale(0.8)` to `scale(1)`, and doing the same for `opacity`.

In this particular sample I have not provided the window spawning animation, but it's easy to evaluate the problem by simply calling `wm_window_scale(window_1, 1.2)` inside JavaScript.

The obvious issue is that the `background-attachment` is now completely ignored, and the blurred version of the background (acrylic blur image) is now occupying the width and height of the parent element, and not the viewport (as it should).
And obviously this deviates from the "immersion" of the application. I do *maybe* know how to fix it using JavaScript, but I want a solution that works without JavaScript, I want plain CSS.

```js
var _dbglog=document.querySelector("#_dbglog .messages");function dbglog(_,e=5e3){var w=document.createElement("div");w.setAttribute("class","message"),w.innerHTML=_,_dbglog.appendChild(w),setTimeout(function(){w.style.width="100%",w.style.height="32px"},0),e>15e3&&(e=15e3),setTimeout(function(){w.remove()},e)}const WM_WINDOW_NULL=4,WM_WINDOW_NOT_ELEMENT=8,WM_WINDOW_NOT_A_WINDOW=22,WM_WINDOW_POSX_NULL=20,WM_WINDOW_POSY_NULL=24,WM_WINDOW_SIZW_NULL=36,WM_WINDOW_SIZH_NULL=40,WM_WINDOW_MOVE_SUCCESS=50,WM_WINDOW_SIZE_SUCCESS=72,WM_WINDOW_MAXIMIZE_SUCCESS=100,WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED=128,WM_WINDOW_RADIUS_PASSED=150,WM_WINDOW_CENTER_PASSED=274,WM_WINDOW_SNAP_LEFT_PASSED=296,WM_WINDOW_SNAP_RIGHT_PASSED=324,WM_WINDOW_SNAP_CENTER_PASSED=352,WM_WINDOW_SCALE_PASSED=374,WM_WINDOW_SCALE_DEFAULTED=402,WM_DESKTOP_SIZE_ZERO=256,abs=_=>Math.abs(_),i2p=function(_){return _+"px"},s2i=function(_){return Number(_.replace(/[aA-zZ]/g,""))};function wm_window_check(_=null){return null==_?WM_WINDOW_NULL:_ instanceof HTMLElement?0==_.getElementsByClassName("titlebar").length?WM_WINDOW_NOT_A_WINDOW:WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED:WM_WINDOW_NOT_ELEMENT}function wm_window_move(_=null,e=null,t=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_move</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+", "+w+", "+h+")");let i=wm_window_check(_);return i!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED?i:null==e?WM_WINDOW_POSX_NULL:null==t?WM_WINDOW_POSY_NULL:(_.style.left=i2p(e),_.style.top=i2p(t),WM_WINDOW_MOVE_SUCCESS)}function wm_window_size(_=null,e=null,w=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_size</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+", "+e+", "+w+")");let t=wm_window_check(_);return t!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED?t:null==e?WM_WINDOW_SIZW_NULL:null==w?WM_WINDOW_SIZH_NULL:(e=abs(e),w=abs(w),_.style.width=i2p(e),_.style.height=i2p(w),WM_WINDOW_SIZE_SUCCESS)}function wm_window_maximize(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_maximize</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);if(e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED)return e;let w=wm_desktop_get_size();if(w==WM_DESKTOP_SIZE_ZERO)return w;var t=Number(_.getAttribute("wm-maximized"));if(_.setAttribute("wm-maximized",Number(!t)),"1"==_.getAttribute("wm-centered")&&_.setAttribute("wm-centered","0"),t){let e=_.getAttribute("wm-last-pos").split(","),w=_.getAttribute("wm-last-siz").split(",");wm_window_move(_,e[0],e[1]),wm_window_size(_,w[0],w[1]),wm_window_radius_enable(_)}else wm_window_move(_,0,0),wm_window_size(_,w[0],w[1]-40),wm_window_radius_disable(_);return WM_WINDOW_MAXIMIZE_SUCCESS}function wm_window_get_size(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_get_size</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);return e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED?e:[s2i(_.style.width),s2i(_.style.height)]}function wm_window_get_position(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_get_position</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);return e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED?e:[s2i(_.style.left),s2i(_.style.top)]}function wm_window_get_position_and_size(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_get_position_and_size</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);if(e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED)return e;let w=wm_window_get_position(_),t=wm_window_get_size(_);return[w[0],w[1],t[0],t[1]]}function wm_desktop_get_size(){dbglog("<b>wm_desktop_get_size</b>()");let _=[desktop.clientWidth,desktop.clientHeight];return 0==_[0]||0==_[1]?WM_DESKTOP_SIZE_ZERO:_}function wm_window_make_movable(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_make_movable</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);if(e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED)return e;dbglog("&gt; Not implemented.")}function wm_window_radius_disable(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_radius_disable</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);if(e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED)return e;let w=_.getAttribute("class");return _.setAttribute("class",w+" no-radius"),WM_WINDOW_RADIUS_PASSED}function wm_window_radius_enable(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_radius_enable</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);if(e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED)return e;let w=_.getAttribute("class");return w=w.replace("no-radius",""),_.setAttribute("class",w),WM_WINDOW_RADIUS_PASSED}function wm_window_center(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_center</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);if(e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED)return e;"1"==_.getAttribute("wm-maximized")&&_.setAttribute("wm-maximized","0");let t=_.getAttribute("wm-last-siz").split(",");w=t[0],h=t[1],wm_window_size(_,w,h);var i=wm_desktop_get_size();wm_window_size(w,h);var n=[i[0]/2-w/2,i[1]/2-20-h/2];wm_window_move(_,n[0],n[1]);var o=Number(_.getAttribute("wm-centered"));return _.setAttribute("wm-centered",Number(!o)),_.setAttribute("wm-last-pos",[n[0],n[1]].join(",")),WM_WINDOW_CENTER_PASSED}function wm_window_snap_left(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_snap_left</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);if(e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED)return e;var w=wm_desktop_get_size();wm_window_get_size(_);return wm_window_move(_,0,0),wm_window_size(_,w[0]/2,w[1]-40),WM_WINDOW_SNAP_LEFT_PASSED}function wm_window_snap_right(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_snap_right</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);if(e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED)return e;var w=wm_desktop_get_size();wm_window_get_size(_);return wm_window_move(_,w[0]/2,0),wm_window_size(_,w[0]/2,w[1]-40),WM_WINDOW_SNAP_RIGHT_PASSED}function wm_window_snap_center(_=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_snap_center</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+")");let e=wm_window_check(_);if(e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED)return e;var w=wm_desktop_get_size(),t=(wm_window_get_size(_),w[0]/3);return wm_window_move(_,w[0]/2-t/2,0),wm_window_size(_,t,w[1]-40),WM_WINDOW_SNAP_CENTER_PASSED}function wm_window_scale(_=null,e=null){dbglog("<b>wm_window_scale</b>("+wm_window_get_id(_)+", "+e+")");let w=wm_window_check(_);return w!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED?w:null==e?(_.style.transform="",WM_WINDOW_SCALE_DEFAULTED):(null!=e&&(_.style.transform="scale("+e+")"),WM_WINDOW_SCALE_PASSED)}function wm_window_get_id(_=null){let e=wm_window_check(_);return e!=WM_WINDOW_CHECK_PASSED?e:_.getAttribute("id").toString()}
```

```css
*{outline:0}body,html{margin:0;padding:0}body{font-family:sans-serif;font-size:17.5px}div,p,span,textarea{font-size:17.5px}#_dbglog{background:rgb(255,255,255,.95);border-radius:4px;box-sizing:border-box;padding:5px 10px;box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4);width:400px;height:auto;position:fixed;left:calc(100vw - 415px);top:15px;display:block;z-index:9999999999}#_dbglog .title{color:#800;font-weight:700}#_dbglog .message{width:0%;height:0;overflow:hidden;box-sizing:border-box;padding:5px 0;font-family:monospace;border-top:1px solid #888;transition:all .2s ease}#_dbglog .message:first-child{margin-top:5px}.bg{background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/MTwwGiZ.jpg")}.fake-acrylic{background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/9pEqYVr.jpg");background-attachment:fixed;background-position:center;background-size:cover;background-repeat:no-repeat;position:absolute;top:-1px;right:-1px;width:calc(100% + 2px);height:calc(100% + 2px);opacity:.6;display:block!important;border-radius:inherit;z-index:0;pointer-events:none}#desktop{background-size:cover;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;background-attachment:fixed;width:100vw;height:100vh;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0}.app-window{background:#fff;border-radius:8px;box-shadow:0 0 64px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);top:0;left:0;transition:left .5s ease,top .5s ease,width .5s ease,height .5s ease,transform .5s ease;position:fixed}.app-window .titlebar{position:relative;height:32px;box-sizing:border-box;top:0;left:0;right:0;width:100%;border-radius:inherit;border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0;cursor:default}.app-window .titlebar .icon{width:32px;height:100%;background-size:24px;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;float:left}.app-window .titlebar .title{height:100%;float:left;box-sizing:border-box;padding:6px 5px}.app-window .titlebar .actions{position:absolute;height:100%;top:0;right:0;border-top-right-radius:inherit}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action{background-size:auto 10px;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;width:40px;height:100%;display:block;transition:background-color .2s ease;float:left}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action:last-child{border-top-right-radius:inherit}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action:hover{background-color:rgba(127,127,127,.33)}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action:active{background-color:rgba(127,127,127,.66)}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action.close:hover{background-color:red}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action.close:active{background-color:rgba(255,0,0,.5)}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action.close{background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKAQMAAAC3/F3+AAAABlBMVEX/AAAAAABBoxIDAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACVJREFUeF4ViUERAAAIgwjgywY2Mdqii3d7ACPLhoGGcgKq0esANL8Df18TT9sAAAAASUVORK5CYII")}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action.maximize{background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKAQMAAAC3/F3+AAAABlBMVEX/AAAAAABBoxIDAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABtJREFUeF5twgENAAAAAUHRRBPtm1HAdiqKvzKPvwl/StkAwQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg")}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action.minimize{background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKAQMAAAC3/F3+AAAABlBMVEX/AAATExO6kg9mAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABhJREFUeF5VwDEBAAAAgjD6p7KZvjis4Q0dDQHAIzU/6gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg")}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action.center{background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKAQMAAAC3/F3+AAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAClJREFUeF4ViFERAAAExZZBAFlU0USV10QVTXC3j20oyGIaB3tepn8qFmvrBycKPOmNAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC")}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action.snap-left{background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKAQMAAAC3/F3+AAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACNJREFUeF4dyLENAAAIw7CcT1l4ibM6IipFGYyhkqBh9q+IOWp8Bv7neXW3AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC")}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action.snap-right{background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKAQMAAAC3/F3+AAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACdJREFUeF4dibkNAAAIhChMXMARHORGdzALn4RQAF6YjhQh+p1fvAZIdwUHHLZZKQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg")}.app-window .titlebar .actions .action.snap-center{background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAKAQMAAAC64i25AAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAACdJREFUeF4NxqERACAMBLDYV10ByxZY9l8EW0dNLooQ7rKPfuNcKB8z2wPH1HpqzgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg")}.app-window .menu{top:32px;left:0;right:0;width:100%;height:28px;box-sizing:border-box}.app-window .menu .option{width:auto;height:inherit;box-sizing:border-box;border:1px solid transparent;display:inline-block;padding:3px;transform:scale(.96);border-radius:6px;cursor:default;transition:background-color .2s ease}.app-window .menu .option:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2)}.app-window .menu .option:active{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6)}.app-window.app-notepad{top:-500px;left:calc(50vw - 300px)}.app-window.app-notepad .textarea{width:100%;height:calc(100% - 92px);box-sizing:border-box;border:0;resize:none;border-top:1px solid #888;border-bottom:1px solid #888;float:left;filter:contrast(90deg)}.no-selections ::selection,.no-selections::selection{background:0 0}.cursor-default,.cursor-default *{cursor:default}.app-window.app-notepad .status-bar{width:100%;height:32px;float:left}.app-window.app-notepad .status-bar .info{display:block;float:right;text-align:left;box-sizing:border-box;padding-top:5.5px}.app-window.app-notepad .status-bar .vr{background-color:#888;width:1px;height:80%;margin:3.5px 5px;float:right}.icon-notepad{background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,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")}.icon-windows-logo{background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACABAMAAAAxEHz4AAAAGFBMVEUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABWNxwqAAAAB3RSTlMASfr1R0gV7qelNgAAAGZJREFUeF7t06ENgEAURMElIWgQNAACTwW0QAfUgKF9OvgGcyHz9GbMv8tTdY9Jt5WTxgEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACWqvVI+r2cZKqar2Q4y0kaSJ/P+Pkh/fw3AgAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8AKEO9ZbE0rsfwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg")}.icon-file-explorer{background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,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")}.taskbar{background:#fff;position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;height:40px;border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);text-align:center;box-sizing:border-box}.taskbar .item{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.3);background-size:24px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;height:100%;width:40px;border:none;display:inline-block;transition:background-color .2s ease,filter .1s ease}.taskbar .item:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6)}.taskbar .item:active{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.9);filter:invert(80%)}.taskbar #taskbar_time{display:inline-block}.taskbar .chunk{height:100%;width:33.32%;box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block}.opacity-0{opacity:0}button{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);border:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);font-size:17.5px;border-radius:4px;transition:background-color .2s ease,border .2s ease}button:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3)}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>CSS `transform` is affecting `background-attachment`</title>
<link rel=stylesheet href=style.css>
</head>
<body>
<div id=_dbglog>
<div class=fake-acrylic></div>
<div class=title>Debug Log <button onclick=this.parentElement.parentElement.remove()>Close</button></div>
<div class=messages>
</div>
</div>
<div id=desktop class=bg>
<div class="app-window app-notepad" id=window_1 style=width:600px;height:400px wm-centered=0 wm-maximized=0 wm-last-pos=150,150 wm-last-siz=600,400>
<div class=fake-acrylic></div>
<div class="titlebar no-selections cursor-default" ondblclick=wm_window_maximize(window_1)>
<div class="icon icon-notepad"></div>
<div class=title>*Untitled - Notepad</div>
<div class=actions>
<div class="action snap-left" onclick=wm_window_snap_left(window_1) title="Snap Left">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="action snap-center" onclick=wm_window_snap_center(window_1) title="Snap Center">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="action snap-right" onclick=wm_window_snap_right(window_1) title="Snap Right">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="action center" onclick=wm_window_center(window_1) title=Center>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="action minimize" onclick='dbglog("Action <b>Minimize</b> not implemented")' title=Minimize>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="action maximize" onclick=wm_window_maximize(window_1) title=Maximize>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="action close" onclick='dbglog("Action <b>Close</b> not implemented")' title=Close>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="menu no-selections cursor-default">
<div class=option onclick='dbglog("Menu option <b>File</b> not implemented")'>File</div>
<div class=option onclick='dbglog("Menu option <b>Edit</b> not implemented")'>Edit</div>
<div class=option onclick='dbglog("Menu option <b>Format</b> not implemented")'>Format</div>
<div class=option onclick='dbglog("Menu option <b>View</b> not implemented")'>View</div>
<div class=option onclick='dbglog("Menu option <b>Help</b> not implemented")'>Help</div>
</div>
<textarea class=textarea spellcheck=false></textarea>
<div class="status-bar no-selections cursor-default">
<div class=info style=width:80px>UTF-8</div>
<div class=vr></div>
<div class=info style=width:140px>Windows (CRLF)</div>
<div class=vr></div>
<div class=info style=width:50px>100%</div>
<div class=vr></div>
<div class=info style=width:120px>Ln 1, Col 1</div>
<div class=vr></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="taskbar no-selections">
<div class="fake-acrylic opacity-9"></div>
<div class=chunk>
<div class="item icon-windows-logo"></div>
<div class="item icon-file-explorer"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script src=main.js></script>
<script>setTimeout(function(){wm_window_center(window_1)},100)</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This may be part of the problem: a transform sets a containing block - so for the fixed background attachment that is used (rather than 'going all the way back up' to the viewport).

Comment: @AHaworth Yeah, that is the problem. The question now is what are the workarounds around that problem that are not way too `hacky`. I tried almost all values for `background-attachment` and its the same story. Though this issue does not only occur on `scale()` but any other functions.

Comment: Could you put that element outside the rest and just fix it, or put a pseudo element on the body and fix that?

Comment: I tried using pseudo-elements, still the same. Also I don't understand what you mean by "outside the rest and just fix it." The idea of the `fake-acrylic` class is to be able to have the effect embedded inside a parent, it be the entire window itself, or a particular element within the window like a sidebar for example. I don't quite have the skillset or understanding of how to do it outside the parent element, or if that's even possible in this case. CSS has lots of weird quirks.

Comment: One would also imagine that transforms shouldn't have an affect on the background, aside from scaling the parent and similar... I don't see why the background can't stay fixed in position when doing a transform. It just seems weird.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. I simply dont see why a background fixed to the viewport is affected by its parents styling/properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. The only solution I could find is the image jumps back to where it should be, when the parent page is scrolled.

```
elmPar.scrollTo({top: 1, behavior: 'instant'});
elmPar.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'instant'});
```

or to maintain the current page scroll position

```
elmPar.scrollBy({top: 1, behavior: 'instant'});
elmPar.scrollBy({top: 0, behavior: 'instant'});
```

or if running in a loop, to avoid jumping in positions in a weird way

```
elmPar.scrollTo({top: elmPar.scrollTop+1, behavior: 'instant'});
elmPar.scrollTo({top: elmPar.scrollTop-1, behavior: 'instant'});
```